# How to get screen position

Tags: go, shiny

I'm using the package `golang.org/x/exp/shiny/screen` in the document, it says that the basic usage to create a screen would be:

```
func main() {
    driver.Main(func(s screen.Screen) {
        w, err := s.NewWindow(nil)
        if err != nil {
            handleError(err)
            return
        }
        defer w.Release()

        for {
            switch e := w.NextEvent().(type) {
            case lifecycle.Event:
                if e.To == lifecycle.StageDead {
                    return
                }
                etc
            case etc:
                etc
            }
        }
    })
}
```

How do I get the position of the screen?

In definition it says that the struct consists of

```
type NewWindowOptions struct {
    // Width and Height specify the dimensions of the new window. If Width
    // or Height are zero, a driver-dependent default will be used for each
    // zero value dimension.
    Width, Height int

    // Title specifies the window title.
    Title string
}
```

So I was thinking of getting this `Width` and `Height`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what are you trying to achieve, I assume you can reuse some parts from the example https://github.com/golang/exp/blob/master/shiny/example/basic/main.go

Below is an excerpt that might be of interest to you:

```
var sz size.Event
for {
    e := w.NextEvent()

    switch e := e.(type) {
        //...
        // Basically wait for the resize event...
        case size.Event:
            // Save the latest size so later you could read it as sz.Bounds()
            sz = e 
        // ...
}
...
```

`sz.Bounds()` returns: https://godoc.org/image#Rectangle and hopefully its `Min`, `Max` points would be absolute locations.